# Where() is not working with strings like "-12345" but does with "12345"

Tags: c#, linq, sitecore8

I have a block of code from a Sitecore 8.1.3 project using LINQ to filter an `IQueryable` collection based on a SOLR index.  We're trying to filter a collection of hotels based on the city selected by the user.

The `HotelSearchResultItem.HotelCity` property is populated from the index and it is a string.  It's value is not the actual city name, but rather is a string representation of the HashCode of the city name... like "12345" or "-12345" depending on the int value of the HashCode. This is what gets indexed, so we're stuck with that format.

The `_facet` variable is the user-chosen city name, and you see that a similar operation is performed on it to convert it to the "12345" HashCode/String format.

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("myIndex");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var hotels = context.GetQueryable<HotelSearchResultItem>()
        .Where( item => item.TemplateId == new ID(TemplateIDs.Hotels.Hotel) );

    var city = _facet
        .GetHashCode()
        .ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

    hotels = hotels
        .Where( item => item.HotelCity == city );

  //more omitted
}
```

The Where clause filters just fine if the values of HotelCity and city are positive like "12345".  But, if the values are negative like "-12345" the resulting collection is empty in scenarios where there are known matches.  I can see the matching strings in the debugger when stepping through.  There are no leading or trailing spaces or other characters.  Also, refactoring this code to a foreach loop using the `==` operator produces the expected matches, which is how I resolved this issue.

Why doesn't LINQ match on the 'negative' strings?  Any insight here?  Thanks.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use hash codes as identifiers, or to persist them.  Two different strings may produce identical hashes.  Worse, the hash value is not guaranteed to be consistent across .NET releases/implementations.  While Microsoft is unlikely to change their hash function (due to the risk of breaking lots of fragile code), what you're doing is a practice best avoided.  Form good habits, avoid bad ones :).

Comment: Have you tried `Where(item => item.HotelCity.Equals(city))`?  `==` and `String.Equals` *should* behave identically,  but this seems like an odd problem, it's worth a shot.

Comment: Also, are you 100% sure that the strings are equal?  No unprintable characters, or odd Unicode characters that just happen to look alike, or anything else strange like that?

Comment: As an addendum to my earlier comment, it appears string hash codes actually *are not* stable in .NET Core.  You likely won't be able to run on ASP.NET Core on Linux, and who knows what else.  Even on the desktop framework, results may vary depending on whether you're running in the x86 or x64 runtime.

Comment: I've done a bunch of quick tests in Fiddle and LINQPad and am unable to reproduce this behavior.  Even when the hash strings are compared using strings from different cultures, it is able to find matches.  I've created a [test Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3MT7oM) for it.

Comment: Hmm, the test code gives negative hashes when run in LINQpad, and positive ones when run in Fiddle.  @MikeStrobel might be on to something with the runtime version.  Is it possible the hashes were generated from different runtime versions?

Comment: Well, if I may suggest a (temporary) alternative, since your `HotelCity` is populated from index, even though its a string it will always be convertable to integer, right? If that's true you could just compare integers instead of strings, aka `var city = _facet.GetHashCode();` and `hotels = hotels.Where(item => Int32.Parse(item.HotelCity) == city);` (this does not leave room for error, you could do your own error checking for valid string beforehand).

Comment: I recommend to debug first `foreach(var item in hotels){if(item.HotelCity != city){Debug.WriteLine("This is the culprit:{0} != {1}", item.HotelCity, city);}}`. Then tell us again what is wrong between the two values... I doubt that it is Linq issue.

Comment: FYI, I ran a test on a [list of world cities](https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database) (~2.3 million unique names), and I saw about a thousand hash collisions under .NET 4.5.  Most were international, but there were some in North America.  In the United States, for example, `Dogwood Acres` and `Charing` hashed identically to `-1088386086`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, thanks for your thoughts on use of hash codes as identifiers.  I agree completely.  Glad I didn't write this code... I just had to fix it, which I did.  Unfortunately this doesn't really address my question which is about the value comparison... linq vs. `==`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, yep, I tried .Equals() with the same result.

Comment: @kurakura88, there are many hotels where `item.HotelCity != city`, and they have obviously different hashcodes, like "32458" != "95840", etc.  I ran the test you suggested and using `==` or `!=` compares the values correctly.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL, giving your idea a try yeilds an exception coming from Sitecore's implementation of LINQ to SOLR:  _Invalid Method Call Argument Type: Field - FieldNode - Field: hotelcityfacet_s - System.String. Only constant arguments is supported._

Comment: Looks like the implementation of LINQ doesn't like the Int32.Parse() call as an argument.  This indicates it may be a Sitecore related issue.

Comment: Pretty grossly wrong practices.  Using GetHashCode() is a very bad idea, its value depends on the framework version and whether the code runs in 32-bit or 64-bit code.  Storing a number in a string column type is a very bad idea and exposes you to formatting conventions, an OS config detail.  Unicode has no less than 13 glyphs that look like a minus sign.  Which of these 17 possible reasons is byting you in the rear end is hard to guess, but it is not Where().

Comment: If you're using an `IQueryable` provider, your predicate is potentially being transformed into who-knows-what and getting evaluated who-knows-where.  When you rewrite it to use a loop, you're retrieving hotels from *all* cities and evaluating your condition locally to filter out just the city you're interested in, as opposed to filtering them remotely and fetching only those that match your query.  With the loop, your filtering happens in-process, as plain old C# code, which oworks as you'd expect, less the obvious issues mentioned above.

Comment: Just in case my last comment was unclear: if your 'fix' is to use a loop instead of `Where`, you are effectively downloading and iterating over your *entire index* with each query.  That would seem to defeat the purpose of using an index.

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with performing another `Where` on an `IQueryable`. On the first `Where`, add a `ToList()` and see if that fixes it, as it will now be `IEnumerable`: `.Where( item => item.TemplateId == new ID(TemplateIDs.Hotels.Hotel) ).ToList()`

Comment: @tic that will be equivalent to filtering using a loop.  It will work, but he'll be fetching the entire index on each query, like I mentioned above.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Debugging should be done if there are too many results to cast to `IEnumerable`. What SQL is generated from the 2nd `IQueryable`? If you run that SQL against the database then does it work or not?

Comment: @MikeStrobel, @HansPassant, and all..
Thanks for your contribution to this thread.  Some conclusions:
First, C# `==` & `!=` obviously compare strings differently than Where().  The heart of my question gets at trying to better understand what Where() is doing and how it is different, so I'll research that.  Any helpful references would be appreciated.
Second, there's a lot wrong with the code sample... GetHashCode(), even use of an index at all - there are less than 200 hotel records in our DB.  These issues are in our backlog.  Sorry these distracted from what I was really trying to ask.

Comment: @MichaelLoftus The way your `Where` predicate gets evaluated depends on your `IQueryable` provider.  It will likely analyze the expression tree, see that you are comparing `HotelCity` against some argument, and attempt to rewrite that into whatever native query language your index uses, then run that native filter remotely.  The idea is to reduce the result set that gets pulled down.  Something isn't translating the way you expect.  See if your Linq provider has a way to view the remote query it constructs—maybe a method you can call on your final `hotels` query like `Dump()` or `Explain()`.

Answer (score 2):

After debugging my query in the Solr Admin panel and reading about the LuceneQParser in the SOLR docs I've found the reason 'negative' values for `facet` were not working (ie: "-12345"):

From the docs:  "[The dash] Prohibits the following term (that is, matches on fields or documents that do not include that term). The - operator is functionally similar to the Boolean operator !. Because it's used by popular search engines such as Google, it may be more familiar to some user communities."

See docs here, the section on Boolean operators:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser

Escaping the `-` with a backslash in the SOLR query got the correct result.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the LINQ provider.  If it's translating the C# expression `HotelCity == "-12345"` to something like `HotelCity: -12435`, then that's not a faithful transformation of intent if `-` is an operator with special meaning.  It's translating your intent (field _equals_ some value) into a directive opposite your intent (field _excludes_ some value) just because the operand happens to contain a symbol with special meaning.  It's the LINQ provider's responsibility to prevent that sort of thing from happening, so it needs to escape your values for you.  File a bug report.